# limit posts to wall on fb app

Tags: facebook, publishing

I have an fb app connected with my website. it will trigger a post to fb user's wall when he completes a search on my site. Is there anyway to have a limit on the number of posts to the wall? say 1 post per day or 3 posts per week?

Comment: I hope you're going to ask them if they want you to post things on their wall every time they run a search on your site ... I would be majorly pissed if a site did that with me explicitly asking for it to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Graph API documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). Basically, Facebook will send you a Graph object for each of the users that log in. You can just keep a table in your DB that maps users to a counter for how many posts you've made to their wall, which you always check before posting to make sure it's not over the limit. When the time period is up, you can just reset the counter.

Here is some example code that will show how to access the Graph object: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Facebook-PHP-API-Applications-Working-with-User-Data/