# On Facebook apps. Can i post 100.000 wall post in a moment with different 100.000 access_tokens?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can i post 100.000 wall post in a moment with different 100.000 access_tokens? or is there a top limit? How can i post at the same time with different access tokens I am begining a new project. I have to consider condition while user number is 100.000 not intent using it as spam. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see how you could possibly post 100,000 wall posts and it *not* be spam.

Comment: You might want to see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293589/limit-posts-to-wall-on-fb-app

Comment: Consider not all access-tokens will be valid so the number of requests are probably a lot more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you are not intending it to be spam facebook very well might see it as spam.  I suggest, rather than sending out **hundreds of thousands of posts at once**, set up a cron job to send smaller chunks of posts to your users.
To the best of my knowledge there is no limit - but as i said, faecbook have many mechanisms to detect suspicious behavior and you might trigger one when your app is found to be sending out so many posts.

Comment: There's also absolutely no policy compliant reason they could have to do this, regardless of how many small batches they use